# Getting "perhaps a missing \item" and double page numbering using longtable

Tags: page-breaking, longtable

I'm trying to get a `longtable` environment to split across pages. Unfortunately, I'm getting a `...perhaps a missing \item` error. Also the document gets a double page numbering where the table splits.

Here's a stripped version of the document.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{hhline}

\newcommand{\ve}{\vspace{.5cm}}
\newcommand{\Hrule}{\rule{\linewidth}{1mm}}

\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\sf #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\sf \thesection\, #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\sf \thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\sf \rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\sf \leftmark}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\sf Olimpiada Mexicana de Matemáticas, 2013}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
   \fancyhead{}
   \fancyfoot{\center{\sf \thepage}}
   \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
   \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Índice de tablas}
\decimalpoint
\setlength{\headheight}{1cm}
\setlength{\headsep}{5pt}
\ChTitleVar{\raggedleft\Large}
\ChNameVar{\Huge}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\thispagestyle{empty}
\vfill
\noindent\Hrule
\begin{flushright}
   {\bf \Huge Olimpiada Mexicana\\ \ve de Matemáticas}
\end{flushright}
\Hrule
\vfill
\begin{center}
   {\bf \Large http://ommenlinea.org/ \\ \ve 2013-2014}
\end{center}

\newpage

\bigskip

\noindent{\bf Nombre 1}\\
Institución 1

\bigskip

\noindent{\bf Nombre 2}\\
Nombre de Facultad,\\
Nombre de Universidad Nacional

\bigskip

\noindent{\bf Nombre 3}\\
Institución 3

\bigskip

\noindent{\bf Nombre 4}\\
Nombre de Facultad,\\
Nombre de Universidad

\newpage

\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Presentación}
\chapter*{Presentación}

\section{Historia de México en las Olimpiadas Internacionales}

\subsection{México en la IMO}
\noindent Los ganadores del primer Concurso Nacional organizado por la Olimpiada Mexicana de Matemáticas asistieron a la XXIX Olimpiada Internacional de Matemáticas, celebrada en Canberra, Australia, en julio de 1988; a partir de ese año México ha asistido a la emisión anual de la Olimpiada Internacional de Matemáticas. Los resultados de las delegaciones mexicanas en las Olimpiadas Internacionales han sido:

\begin{center}
    \begin{longtable}{|c|l|c|c|}
        \hhline{-|-|-|-|}
        {\it Año} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\it País sede} & {\it No. de países} & {\it Lugar de México}\\
        \hhline{|=|=|=|=|}
        \endfirsthead
        \hhline{-|-|-|-|}
        \multicolumn{4}{|r|}{\it ...contin\'ua de la página previa} \\
        \hhline{-|-|-|-|}
        {\it Año} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\it País sede} & {\it No. de países} & {\it Lugar de México}\\
        \hhline{|=|=|=|=|}
        \endhead
        \hhline{-|-|-|-|}
        \multicolumn{4}{|r|}{\it Contin\'ua en la siguiente página...} \\
        \hhline{-|-|-|-|}
        \endfoot
        \endlastfoot
        1988 & Australia & 49 & 37\\
        1989 & Rep. Fed. de Alemania & 50 & 31\\
        1990 & Rep. Popular de China & 54 & 36\\
        1991 & Suecia & 55 & 35\\
        1992 & Rusia & 56 & 49\\
        1993 & Turquía & 73 & 63\\
        1994 & Hong Kong & 69 & 65\\
        1995 & Canadá & 74 & 59\\
        1996 & India & 75 & 53\\
        1997 & Argentina & 82 & 32\\
        1998 & Taiwan & 75 & 44\\
        1999 & Rumania & 81 & 52\\
        2000 & Corea & 82 & 30\\
        2001 & Estados Unidos & 83 & 46\\
        2002 & Escocia & 84 & 46\\
        2003 & Japón & 82 & 41\\
        2004 & Grecia & 84 & 37\\
        2005 & México & 91 & 31\\
        2006 & Eslovenia & 90 & 24\\
        2007 & Vietnam & 92 & 37\\
        2008 & España &  97 & 37\\
        2009 & Alemania &  104 & 50\\
        2010 & Kazajistán & 97 & 33\\
        2011 & Holanda & 101 &  22\\
        2012 & Argentina & 100 & 31\\
        2013 & Colombia & 97 & 17\\
        \hhline{-|-|-|-|}
    \end{longtable}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

How could this be solved?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Don't use `center` around `longtable`.

Comment: @egreg Does `longtable` gets the table centred automatically?

Comment: @Pablo: Yes. `longtable` has an optional argument to control the horizontal alignment; possible values are `l` (left), `r` (right), `c` (centered); the default is `c`.

Comment: Thank you for the information! It's been really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mustn't enclose a `longtable` in a `center` environment; the horizontal centering is done automatically, unless otherwise specified.

The `longtable` environment has an optional argument

```
\begin{longtable}[<pos>]{<spec>}
```

where `<pos>` can be `l`, `r` or `c` (the last one is the default). One can also act on the length parameters `\LTleft` and `\LTright`, for different effects (an example is on page 6 of the package manual).